# Cognito Forms: copy text from other document

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to copy / paste text from other documents and get the error: Please use Ctrl+V/Cmd+V keyboard shortcuts to paste contents

I AM using Crtl + V to try and paste the text into the content page field, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

We have determined that this is an issue in newer versions of Chrome and FireFox.  The short story here is that older versions of these browsers did not support pasting formatted content from products like Microsoft Word, so a plugin was required to convert the pasted content to make it work.  This plugin does not play nice with newer browser versions but is also no longer required, so we are testing to see if we can remove it entirely.

In the mean time, try using Internet Explorer or Edge.  Also, if you only need the text content (not the formatting) right click in Chrome and select Paste as Text, or you can paste the content first into a text editor and then paste into [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).